# Fixing corrupt firmware on a HP Laserjet CM 1312 MFP when I have no longer got the driver installed

Tags: hp-laserjet

The firmware on my HP Laserjet CM1312 MFP was corrupted during an update.  I never fixed it and later the computer with the driver installed was broken.

I now can't reinstall the firmware on the printer because I do not have the driver installed; I cannot install the driver because the firmware is corrupt.

Does anyone have any idea how I can install the driver, or update the firmware?

Answer (score -1):

- Go into device manager then find all the drivers installed manually and delete them
- then go into manufacture website and install the new ones
- You can even try with system restore

Comment: Did you read the question properly? "I cannot install the driver because the firmware is corrupt."

Comment: Try to install drivers manually by choosing Have a disk in device manager and locate INF file in drivers if compressed then extract using 7z works for compressed exe files. Link for manually driver installations: http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1473-how-to-force-a-manual-driver-isntall-in-win-7